# Are REST calls from WebSphere Application Server to another server visible?

Tags: java, rest, oauth, websphere

Say that I'm running an application on WebSphere Application Server and in some Java class, it makes a REST call by providing a client and client secret to receive a refresh token for OAuth2, and then later at some point, it also makes a REST call to by providing the refresh token to receive an access token.

The source code is obviously not going to be visible to debug through and inspect these values, but my question is that can the values being passed in these REST calls (namely the client secret and refresh token) and the response (access token) be viewed by someone who has access to the machine running the server?

The reason I ask is that I am thinking of storing these unchanging values (client id, client secret, refresh token) somewhere where they cannot be viewed by anyone other than through a JDBC connection in the Java code, and I plan to use these values for authentication purposes with some server somewhere. I do not want the person who this application is being used by to be able to view these values because if they can, they can do some damage by accessing other public APIs on the server.

I intend to only let the Java code (backend) interact with the server for authentication and grabbing some resource, but I do not want to allow the person who has access to this machine (but does not have access to where these values are stored) to view the details of the REST request and response.

Thank you.

Comment: **can the values being passed ... be viewed by someone who has access to the machine running the server?** Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you asking if the data you send to a server can be accessed by someone who has access to this server? Think about that for a second...

Comment: I think you've added a bunch of extra fluff (Websphere, REST, etc) to your question that is irrelevant. Read my above comment, and you have your answer.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I mean but how is this possible? As in, say for example's sake that the Java code has some hardcoded values (and the source is not visible) and a REST call is made in the Java code using these values. How can someone who has access to the machine view the request and response?

Comment: First, Java is easily [decompiled](http://jd.benow.ca/). You can't rely on compiled Java source to be secure, and definitely not hard-coded values. You can open the class files with a text editor and view the strings. Second, every bit of network traffic is easily inspected with network monitoring tools.

Comment: This is really security 101 day one... If someone has physical access to a machine, you cannot guarantee anything passing through/stored on that server is secure. This is why you lock your servers up.

Comment: OK maybe hardcoded string was a bad example. But say that the information is encrypted in some database somewhere that is later accessed using JDBC and decrypted in the Java code.

If an HTTPS connection is formed, then all traffic between the two machines should be encrypted and secure, no? How would someone be able to use some monitoring tools to see the contents of the request and response? I'm sure they can view the server address but the content of the requests/responses?

Comment: This feels like a moving target... Plain and simple: If someone has physical access to a machine, they have access to everything going in/out of that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear which server you're referring to in various places.

If you make an outbound HTTPS request from a WebSphere server to a 2nd server, you have to assume all details of the request and response are visible to the operators of the software on **both** sides.

Either side can trace all of its own input and output.

Comment: Could you explain HOW the side making the request can trace the request and response when an HTTPS request (ex: a REST call) is made?

Comment: The exact mechanics and options would depend on a lot of things. Do you doubt that If you use a common HTTP client, even over HTTPS, someone in control of the system couldn't get it to trace/dump the data in/out?   Or the backend side could arrange for you to not use a HTTPS cipher offering forward secrecy and capture/decrypt your data outside of the stack.  Or they could get the server or client SW to persist your ephemeral DH keys and then go on to decode the session.

Net, you ultimately need to trust both sides with your secrets.